# Access file selected through a form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following Ruby code which includes a form to select a file:

```
 <%= form_for :import, :url=>{:controller=>"user", :action=>"upload"}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
        <div class= "field">
            <%= f.file_field :import %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Import' %>
        </div>
```

Inside my controller I am trying to call the file that the user selected from their local disk.
 The below code works when I give it the file:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open 'c:/myexcel.xls'
```

But I am not sure how to inside a controller call up the file that was selected from the form.
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do this with **CarrierWave**, see railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) .

Heres the code to import data from an Excel spreadsheet:

```
def upload
    require 'spreadsheet'
    Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
    file_to_import = params[ :import ][ :import ]
    file = FileUploader.new
    file.store!(file_to_import)
    book = Spreadsheet.open "#{file.store_path}"
    sheet = book.worksheet 0
    sheet.each 1 do |row|
        @user = User.new(:code => row[0], :name => row[1], :status => row[2], :account => current_user.account).save
  end
```

Alternatively for uploading files and retrieving them you could use the '**paperclip**' gem (railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) ).

It is quite old but its a respected gem which is well supported and hasn't changed much.

Hope that helps

Comment: will try that with CarrierWave and the code you have given, thanks